# How to watch .sss files and re-run my npm script if they change

Tags: node.js, npm, postcss

Is there a way to watch my .sss files and re-run this if they change?

```
"css": "postcss -u autoprefixer -u postcss-easy-import -p sugarss src/index.sss -o src/index.css"
```

I can't find a way, I've looked on the net all over.  I don't see any kind of watch available from postcss.  There's a -w or --watch with the postcss-cli but I tried adding that to the end of the script above.  Unless I'm just doing it wrong, my css script does not re-run itself if my .sss files change.

maybe there's some generic node watcher lib I can use?

Comment: You can use [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) and use the code `nodemon -e sss -exec "npm css" `

Comment: what if I want my files to recompile and I'm simply coding away locally but my app isn't started?

Comment: I don't normally do development as my app is running.

Comment: I really just want to act like I'm running a certain npm script locally on change of certain files (when my app is NOT running).  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: weird I tried this, and it restarts my app but doesn't seem to run my "css" script before the page refreshes "watch": "nodemon -e sss -exec \"yarn run css\""

Comment: `nodemon -e sss --exec "npm run css"`

Comment: I forgot `-` in `--exec`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145592/discussion-between-ezzat-and-positiveguy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) is a very powerful tool to re-run your scripts based on any change in your files , default file extension for `nodemon` to watch is `.js` and default script to run from your `package.json` file is `start` script.

You can overwrite watched extension using `-e` option , then extensions separated by `,` for example `-e sss` in your case.

Also you can overwrite the script you want to run using `--exec` option and then pass the script you want to run , in your case it will be `--exec "npm run css"`

And put all together `nodemon -e sss --exec "npm run css"` , this will watch changes in `sss` files and run `css` script